# Retrieve elements with max occurences with a DRAW(tie) in the max occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, list, count, max

Eg., I have the following list
[s, d, s, e, d, d, s]

I need to print the elements with highest occurrences.
example output:
d 2
s 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z5rI.png)

So far, i have been able to get only one element with highest occurrence. Please help me deal with the tie or draw in the max occurrence.

Comment: Do you even have a DataFrame or Series?

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your _dataframe_, not just your list? I can give you the code then.

Comment: @user17242583 Please check the Image that I have added.

I also need to get S 2 along with d 2 in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
counts = df[0].value_counts()
counts = counts[counts == counts.max()]
```

Output:

```
>>> counts
s    3
d    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64

>>> counts['s']
3

>>> counts['d']
3
```